# React Native: How to trigger remote fetch when switching back to tab based on state

Tags: react-native, react-redux, react-navigation

I am building an app with 2 tabs (`react-navigation`). I am new to `react` and `redux` and I am still trying to wrap my head around how to communicate between components without creating too many unnecessary dependencies.

**Tab A:** The main component is fetching data via a remote API. For this I am using a `react-redux` and `redux-thunk`. The data is kept inside the central store since it is used for button states across different components (Tab A and Tab B). Pressing a button is calling a Thunk that deals with the asynchronous API call to update the server and then dispatches the action to update the store.

**Tab B:** Also fetches its data via a remote API but sets it via the component's `State`. I did not see the point of also putting this into the redux store since it is not shared across components. The button component from Tab A is also used here.

**What I am trying to achieve:** When the state inside the redux store changes (button's `onPress()` dispatches an action) both Tab A and Tab B require to re-fetch via the remote API but only under the following circumstances:

- Switching from one tab to the other requires a re-fetch inside the target tab. Then, only when switching back to the first tab it should also trigger a re-fetch.

**What I considered:**

Adding a `tabAinvalidated` and `tabBinvalidated` flag to the redux store. I then listen to the `willFocus` event inside both tabs. I then re-fetch if the respective tab is flagged as invalidated. This might work but I am not sure if it is considered an anti-patter to keep update flags for individual components inside the redux store.

**Q:** Is there a better approach to this? What is the best way in react native to inform components that they need to reload their data from a remote API?

Answer (score 0):

I think I came up with a solution myself. Instead of using the boolean flags for each tab (`tabAinvalidated`, `tabBinvalidated`) I am now just recording a timestamp for every update inside the redux store. For components which require re-fetching based on redux store updates I copy the redux timestamp into their own component's State each time I re-fetch the data. This way I can check if the component needs to re-fetch its own data from the server.

```
  setFocus = async() => {
    if (this.props.updateTs > this.state.updateTs) {
        await this.loadData()
        this.setState({ updateTs: this.props.updateTs, })
    }
  }
```

Seems to work fine.